# Is it possible to create a "Do Not Contact" list in REDCap that could be shared across many projects?

Tags: redcap

I would like all projects utilizing surveys on our REDCap installations to be able to incorporate a *Do Not Contact* list for automated emails.

My hope was to have a simple survey project that had two fields:

- Email, with variable name primary_email
- Reason to not be contacted, a checkbox with a few options

If this is created, call it Project 1, could a new unrelated project (Project 2) be set up with automated survey invitations that included a condition that the email address is not currently in Project 1?

I imagine there is some type of SQL involved, but am not sure exactly where to put it.

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN a.value IS NOT NULL THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT value FROM redcap_data WHERE project_id = '9999' AND field_name = 'primary_email'
) AS a,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT value FROM redcap_data WHERE project_id = '7777' AND field_name = 'main_email'
) AS b
WHERE a.value = b.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have a separate project for your do-not-call register. In research studies you could think of this as withdrawal; if a participant has withdrawn then they should not be sent future invitations. I'll refer to 'Opt-out' but feel free to substitute something like 'Do not call' or 'Withdrawal' as needed.

Create an instrument called Opt-out, which has minimally a field `[opt_out]` with label "I opt out" and a choice `1, Yes` (plus whatever else you need to record; reason, date, etc).

In any communications to participants, include a survey link to this `opt_out` instrument using `[survey-link:opt-out]` at the end, maybe something like:

`<small>You may opt-out of this study by clicking [survey-link:opt_out:here].</small>`

Then, in all communications, add a term to the logic, so that the alert/ASI sends only if:

`<existing logic> AND [opt_out] <> '1'`

And be sure to check the box labeled "Ensure logic is still true before sending".

**If your project is longitudinal** then this `opt_out` instrument needs to be designated on an event. I would create an event for administrative stuff like this, or adverse events, randomisation, or anything not pertaining to other specific events. Let's say the event is `admin_arm_1`, your survey link needs to be prepended with this unique event name, as does the check on the `opt_out` field in the logic.

With this setup, participants can easily click through to the survey where they can withdraw or opt-out, and when they do so, any scheduled alerts and ASIs get removed before they are sent.